# url access HTML5 History API

Tags: javascript, html

in using the History API such as `pushState(data,title,url)` and `replacestate(data,title,url)` how can I access the url entered in other words when I hit the back button I want to check the url entered so that I can try and rebuild he function to call.

Comment: eh... document.location?

Answer (score 0):

[`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties), see also the [`hashchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange).